# Package Manager: using Enable-Migrations for a specific project in the solution

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, package-managers

I have a visual studio 2012 solution consisting of two VB.Net project (ASP .NET MVC 4). I am using Entite Framework code first with one of the project but I am not using Entity Framework at all for the second project. As I was writing the code for one of the entities I wrote the following code:

```
Public Class TacheDeReference
    Inherits BaseModel

    Public DescriptionTache As String


End Class
```

Instead of writing:

```
Public Class TacheDeReference
    Inherits BaseModel

    Public Property DescriptionTache As String


End Class
```

But before realizing my mistake I had already regenerate the solution and run it and accessed some of the crud user interfaces resulting from the Entity Framework Code First scaffolding process.

Now when I made the above change I ran into the following error message:

> The model backing the 'BlogContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database ( http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

As I followed the linked in order to go through the migration process, the first instruction was to run the `Enable-Migrations`command in the package manager console.

When I ran that command I had another error message telling me that Entity Framework is not installed on one of my projects, which is normal since it is installed only on one project

See the image below

[image: PM Console error]

My question: How can I run the `Enable-Migrations`**for a specific projet** **and not for the whole solution?**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The answer to the following question solves my issue


  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533922/error-the-entityframework-package-is-not-installed-on-project

Comment: You must specify correct project in your 'Projet par defaut:' You AweVbDemo does not have installed EF so you must specify project that has installed EF.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Package Manger Console you have Default project dropdown list. Check that you select your project that has installed Entity Framework in it and not the **AweVbDemo** project because EF is not installed on that project.

You have the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21534049/1081079
and I provided the same answer there so it is duplicated question

Comment: Thanks. I found out about that questions a few minutes after posting. Thanks anyway